# Is there any simple printer I can install on WINE?

Tags: wine, printing

I have a legacy Windows application that I would like to use with WINE. This application requires a printer to work:

> Please install default printer.

I was wondering whether there's some kind of printer driver that I can download and install to make the program work. I've tried PDFCreator, but it doesn't want to install (it says that it's not compatible with my "version of Windows"), and I've also tried installing cups-pdf on the Linux VM but it didn't make a difference.

I suppose I need to install a printer in WINE's own environment (so it needs to be a Windows printer driver). Is there anything I could easily use to deal with this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install `printer-driver-cups-pdf` (or `cups-pdf` for Ubuntu 15.10 and earlier) a PDF printer is added which saves the printed files in `~/PDF/`. All the printers installed in your Ubuntu OS also work from WINE, you don't need to do anything about it.

#### But:

If you just normally installed CUPS on your 64-bit Ubuntu (`uname -r` gives `x86_64` if it is 64-bit), this won't work when you run a 32-bit software like yours from 1995 presumably is. The solution in this case is to install the 32-bit CUPS library, so that 32-bit WINE is also able to find your printers:

```
sudo apt install libcups2:i386
```